# Should turf be laid above, below or flush with existing ground level?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair, sod

When patching a section of an existing lawn, should the turf be laid

a) *very slightly* above existing ground level (to allow for settling)

b) *very slightly* below existing ground level (to give it more protection from drying out)

c) completely flush with the existing ground level

[image]

Answer (score 7):

When placing turf/sod patches into an existing lawn I will initially install them approximately 1inch (25mm) higher than the existing lawn, then using a combination of a scaffold board and my weight I will "settle" the newly installed patches so they are level or very! slightly above the existing lawn.

[How to drain lawn with very little slope?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/how-to-drain-lawn-with-very-little-slope/1515#1515)

> - Bring in enough 50-50 mix of "good" quality screened top soil & "good" quality screened compost to level the excavated area into the surrounding lawn area. Finished level should be approximately 1inch (25mm) below new finished lawn level.
> - Lay back the properly stacked lawn (sod), it should be sitting approximately 1inch (25mm) higher than required new finished lawn level.
> - Lay a scaffold-board over the top of the reinstalled lawn (sod). Shuffle along the board a few times, this will ensure you get good contact between the lawn (sod) and the soil underneath. Move the board over the width of the board, repeat "shuffle" process. Repeat, repeat... until you've tamped down the complete reinstalled lawn (sod) area.
> - Water the reinstalled lawn area so it's moist. Repeat this watering daily for a week or so. After that, if there is no rain, water entire lawn as you would normally.

[How to fill low spots over existing grass in my yard?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/how-to-fill-low-spots-over-existing-grass-in-my-yard/1767#1767)

> - Add your fill material (see below for recommendation).
>
>   - If adding more than 4inch (100mm) depth of material, add in 4inch (100mm) layers, each layer should be "lightly" tamped down (do not over compact).
> - Carefully lay back your sod, the sod should sit approximately 1 inch (25mm) above your finished required level ie The relaid sod should be sitting high.
>
>   - Lay a scaffold board (or similar) over the relaid sod, shuffle up and down the board a few times. This will ensure good contact is made between the fill material and the sod, and the sod will lower (settle) to it's new final required level.
> - Sprinkle a thin layer (¼ to ½inch / 6.25 to 12.5mm) of compost over the area you've finished bringing up to grade.
> - Water once a day for the next 7 days, so the area remains moist (but not saturated).
>
>   - After that time, water your entire lawn as you would normally.

Answer (score 5):

Lay it on top of the prepared soil, and around the edges move some of the soil out in order to leave it flush with the adjacent ground. This will work in most situations. If you live in an extremely dry area you would want to leave it slightly below the surrounding ground.